# Java Variables in Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I've read a few question/answers here but am still a hair confused on how java threading and variables work.

My software opens a continuous URL listener for some events connecting some jacked up version of the REST API, but I'll digress.  So here's a summarized block of code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //open the long-running URL
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Start to receive the event notification.
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));


    // Read a complete event. Process the event.
    String str = sb.toString();
    sb.delete(0, sb.length());

    // Parse the alarm and send to the sub-processor if necessary 
    log4j.debug("Start Event Parsing");
    ParseAlarm.parseXML(str);
    Thread newAlarm = new Thread(new CreateAlarm());
    newAlarm.start();
}
```

Mind you this is all to fix a bug where if a 2nd event is received before the parsing completes, one of them gets lost.

1. If I move `ParseAlarm.parseXML(str)` into the newAlarm thread (which fires additional threads to maintain order) do all of the sub-threads have access to the public variables (some are arrays, some are ints/strings) declared in parseXML or do I need to pass the variables to each sub-thread?
2. If the public variables declared in parseXML are available to all of the sub-threads of newAlarm, what happens if newAlarm is triggered again by the main script?  Do the public parseXML variables clash with the ones in the other thread?

ParseAlarm is as such.  Sparing the irreverent portions of code.  Mind you it's not setup for threading yet.

```
public class ParseAlarm {

  public static int intAlarmID;
  public static String strAlarmDesc;
  public static Map<String, String> mXML = new HashMap<String, String>();

public static void ParseXML(String strXML) throws Exception {
  for (int i = 0; i < arElementList.length; i++) {
   //parse the elements in the XML
  }
 // Create the alarm ID as an integer for the alarm acknowledgement and the alarm description for the filter 
    intAlarmID = Integer.parseInt(mXML.get("id"));
    strAlarmDesc = mXML.get("alarmDesc");
}

}
```

I have been able to access the variables declared public from other threads by referencing the them as such:
    public static Map mAlarm = ParseAlarm.mXML;
    private int intID = ParseAlarm.intAlarmID;

Is this not supposed to happen or am I completely doing this wrong?

Comment: You can never access variables declared in a method (`ParseXML()`) from outside the method.

Comment: Is `ParseAlarm` an instance, or is `ParseAlarm.ParseXML()` a static method. It's hard to tell because you're not following the naming conventions (camelCase).

Comment: And `CreateAlarm` seems like an unusual name for a class.

Comment: The whole concept of variable scope and visibility in Java is entirely a compile-time construct (aside from reflection, but I digress). It sounds like you're mistakenly tying it to runtime behavior.

Comment: "public variables declared in parseXML". Since `parseXML()` is a method, there can be no public variables declared there. Only local variables which aren't seen by any other threads and exist only for the duration of the method.

Comment: Threads don't contain variables, they don't contain objects, and they don't contain other threads.  Threads basically are demons that _execute_ your code.  Your program always starts with one thread---the one that executes your `main(...)` routine, and that thread can unleash other threads if that's what your code tells it to do.

Comment: @Kayaman I've added the abbreviated code and how I have been referencing them.  I may be completely doing this wrong, I'm accustomed to PHP and I'm not that grand at that either.

Comment: @AaronK.Baxter Well, those static variables in your `ParseAlarm` mean that multiple threads calling `ParseXML` at the same time will all use the same variables, guaranteeing in things going wrong. Why not move `ParseXML()` and the variables to `CreateAlarm` class, and make the variables non-static. Then you'll have each `CreateAlarm` instance working nicely by themselves and not bother each other.

Comment: @Kayaman So, the IDA seems happy if I take all references to static out.  Now my question becomes if I move ParseXML() into CreateAlarm, can I make it a thread and still be able to access the public variables like I have been?  I fear there might be an instance where the parsing doesn't complete before the filter thread starts (where I think it already has been as things have been missing the filter).

Comment: @AaronK.Baxter I don't know how much relevant information is lost in the question, but based on what I see I would get the input `String`, create the new thread and pass the string there, parsing the input on the processing thread. When the parsing is done it would then process or pass the results to any further place (for example through a queue). Your polling of public variables is a poor approach. I'm also worried about "..into the newAlarm thread (which fires additional threads to maintain order)" part. Firing additional threads to maintain order? I think you have too many threads already.

Comment: @Kayaman Yea, this was one of those "hurry up and get it working" jobs so I didn't have time to learn the "correct way".  It'll eventually get rewritten or deprecated, one of the two.  I'm sure there is a better way, but if I simply rely on procedural order, I run into race conditions and threads with waits are the only way I know how to handle it.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for all of the assistance.  I've gone back and re-coded it to not use statics and create new instances of my classes as it runs.  Wish I could accept a comment as an acceptable answer :)